# Windows authentication mode looking for a username/password

Tags: windows, authentication

I hope you can help me. I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application running under IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box. When we try to access the application it looks for a username & password in  a "Windows Security" panel.

We are confused to say the least! Obviously we checked the following:

- The web.config says  is enabled
- IIS says "Anonymous Authentication" is disabled (which is what we want)
- IIS Says "Windows Authentication" is enabled (which is what we  want)
- We have bounced IIS and the server
- We had a look at the applicationHost.config and it looks okay (but to be honest there is a lot there)
- On IE 11 - the localhost website is added already as a trusted site

Has anyone encountered this before? Would appreciate any suggestions/comments/user-experience you may be able to share...

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config, do you have  and make sure the anonymous authentication is enabled.

Comment: Yes. I added it into the Web.config: <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" /> but its still not working on the actual server itself. However it is working when I use my own pc to view the application site...

Comment: Part of my answer was cut of <allow users='*'></allow> should be there as well.

Comment: Just curious, did you disable all other authentication methods besides anonymous in IIS for the apps?

Comment: Hi Goran, to be honest - it was a combination of errors in the web.config and incorrect permission on the actual folder. Anonymous is enabled as is windows authentication on the root folder. Sub folders need asp.net impersonation for this project I have but as I say - permissions on the main folder were the key to my problem. Hope this helps. J.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Anonymous Authentication disabled you will be asked to provide credentials, since they are not being specified in the Anonymous Authentication settings.

You state

> IIS Says "Windows Authentication" is enabled (which is what we 
>   want)

and that is exactly what the system is doing, IIS is performing as it should as per your settings since you have Anonymous Authentication disabled.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What we want is any user on the same domain to be able to access the application without entering their details. We are using active director also. Should we not set anonymous authentication to false therefore?

Comment: You might be missing the Domain permissions in your application folder. Go to the site in IIS, right click on it, click Edit Permissions, go the security Tab, add the group or users you want accessing the site, and that should eliminate the prompting.